# Windows Phone app

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8

If I have published a new version of my app on Windows Store, I want the user using old version of my app to be notified when launching the app.

Currently, I am able to fetch current app version installed on phone and can redirect to store. How I can get my app version on store. Please suggest me the right way to get version on store.

To get current version using following code:-

```
 var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver()
        };

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("WMAppManifest.xml", xmlReaderSettings))
        {
            xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("App");

            return xmlReader.GetAttribute("Version");
        }
```

To redirect to windows store using following code:-

```
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("ms-windows-store:navigate?appid={0}", appid));
                await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

How should I get apps version on Windows store?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to force a windows phone to update your app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223555/is-it-possible-to-force-a-windows-phone-to-update-your-app)

Comment: this is not working in my case. method is returning as null and not computed.

Comment: I have tried same code. can you please suggest me any another approach?